# Свойства класса объектного типа, их запись в Hibernate и мэппинг DTO/Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, rest, jpa

У меня есть класс сущности:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    private TypeReport typeReport;

}
```

Для этого класса создан класс DTO:

```
@Data
public class GroupDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private TypeReport typeReport;

}
```

Настроен Mapper. При запросах к RestController с клиента передается и получается DTO. Например:

```
 @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<GroupDTO> createGroup(@RequestBody GroupDTO groupDTO) {
        Group group = groupMapper.fromGroupDTO(groupDTO);
        group = groupService.createGroup(group);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(groupMapper.toGroupDTO(group), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Сложность в следующем, поле TypeReport так же является сущность и имеет свою DTO. Так же записывается базу данных. Но TypeReport не должно записываться при записи Group.

Вопрос, как правильно работать с TypeReport?

1. В GroupDTO сооздать поля примитивных типов long и string, а при мэппинге из/в DTO преобразовывать эти значения в объект?
2. Указать в качестве типа поля typeReport в классе GroupDTO класс сущности TypeReport?
3. Указать в качестве типа поля typeReport в классе GroupDTO класс DTO, т.е. TypeReportDTO и при мэппинге из/в GroupDTO так же производить мэппинг поля typeReport из/в TyperReportDTO?

Нужно ли в свойствах объектов DTO использовать так же классы DTO?

На клиенте в поле typeReport я записываю только его код, другие поля в этом месте мне не нужны. Соответстственно с клиента на сервер, например при запросе на создание, приходит объект Group вида:

```
{
    title: "Группа"
    typeReport: {
        id: 1
    }
}
```

Соответственно при записи Group в базу одного id для typeReport Hibernate достаточно, чтобы правильно сохранить идентификатор ссылающийся на typeReport.

Answer (score 0):

В GroupDto вместо typeReport передавайте поле typeReportId с идентификатором